# HTML / CSS - How do I embed external fonts (files) into an html page without referencing as a separate file?

Tags: html, css

I have a template used for an email that I originally have linked to external font files in my testing environment.

This email template relies upon custom fonts which I want to load into an email html page.  Initially I load them into the file using a file  link.

However, when I use this in an email, I will not be able to refer to the external file.

Is it possible to embed the font file into the html page without relying on loading it as a separate file from css, preferable without using a public link on the web?

Comment: In theory that is possible - go research _Data URI_. But many clients/web interfaces that display emails remove `<style>` elements as well, and only allow inline styling. In that case, even inline-ing the fonts won’t do any good. Plus, depending on the font, it can increase the amount of mail data that needs to be send massively. // Custom fonts in e-mails are a bad idea IMHO. Time to tell the designer who insisted on it(?) to back down, and accept reality.

Comment: Thank you for the response.   I will make the font non custom.

Comment: @CBroe is absolutely right.  You might be able to achieve this result through `data uri` - but even then you're going to HAVE to provide a fallback for the massive number of e-mail clients (Like Gmail) that either strip out inline styles or have a whitelist for what is allowed.  Given the necessity of a fallback, it seems wise to reconsider whether this approach is worth the effort.

Comment: I usually use an image for the parts with custom fonts (as they are easier to embed) then you can make your web page alternate with link to it for people who are having trouble viewing the email